# Database schema dilemmas

Tags: database-design

I am developing database scheme for recipes database.
Do you have some ideas how to enchance my existing model? My bigges concern is RECIPE_INGREDIENT table.
[image]

Comment: is this for school? it smells like a school problem. sorry if i'm wrong.

Comment: No its my pet project. I have designed this schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RECIPE_INGREDIENT you can safely remove the RECIPE_INGREDIENT_ID and replace it with (INGREDIENT_ID, RECIPE_ID) as combined primary key, similiar to the recipe_tags table. That is unless you plan to allow an ingredient to appear twice in a recipe.

Otherwise the design looks fine to me. What do you want to improve? It might help if you explain what you're trying to accomplish with the database and which queries you plan to run.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really see what you're trying to enhance. I don't have a lot of experience with databases, but this seems to be normalized correctly. The only thing I wonder about is the inclusion of INGREDIENT_DESC in RECIPE_INGREDIENT instead of keeping it with the ingredient itself in RM_INGREDIENT.

Comment: I am trying to enchance RM_RECIPE_INGREDIENT table. Should I add INGREDIENT_ID PFK in table RECIPE_INGREDIENT. I dont want to add recipe steps.

Comment: The way I interpret this table thats perfectly reasonable if it is used for descriptions on how to prepare the ingredient for the recipe.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you would have some sort of process or step that a recipe has many of which has many ingredients.

Recipe 1 - Many  Recipe Step

Recipe Step 1 - Many Recipe Ingredients

Comment: I am trying to enchance RM_RECIPE_INGREDIENT table. Should I add INGREDIENT_ID PFK in table RECIPE_INGREDIENT. I dont want to add recipe steps.